# React Native Animated: how to detect moment when animated element cross given position

Tags: reactjs, react-native, animation, react-animated, react-native-reanimated

How to detect when an animated element has reached a certain position.
The element should not stop in this position.
It should continue the off-screen animation.

When an element exceeds the given position (line), I have to trigger some action (e.g. change the color of the line to red).

[image]

```
const Component = () => {
  const moveAnimX = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

  const runAnimation = () => {
    Animated.timing(moveAnimX, {
      toValue: 2000, // out of screen
      duration: 1500, 
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    runAnimation();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Animated.View
      style={[
        {
          height: 50,
          width: 50,
          backgroundColor: 'red',
          transform: [
            {
              translateX: moveAnimX,
            },
          ],
        },
      ]}
    />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged the question with react-native-reanimated, here's how I would do it using Reanimated 2.  You could probably translate this to use the RN Animated API.

1. Get the line's x coordinate.  If you don't set it imperatively, you could measure it with onLayout (shown below), or native methods if you need to know its position on the screen.
2. Make a shared value that represents the x offset of the square.
3. Create two animated styles - one for the position of the square, one for the color of the line.
4. In the animated style for the color of the line, interpolate the x offset   so that when the value is below that, it returns one color, and above that, returns another.
5. Animate.

Pseudocode below

```js
import Animated, {
  interpolateColor,
  useAnimatedStyle,
  useSharedValue,
  withTiming,
} from 'react-native-reanimated';
...

  const [lineX, setLineX] = useState(0);
  const squareOffsetX = useSharedValue(0);
  const animatedSquareStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => ({
    left: squareOffsetX,
  });
  // the destination offset of the square - substitute whatever makes sense
  const { width: screenWidth } = Dimensions.get('screen');
  
  const animatedLineStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => ({
    backgroundColor: interpolateColor(
      squareOffsetX.value,
      [0, lineX - 1, lineX, screenWidth],
      ['black', 'black', 'red', 'red']
    ),
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    squareOffsetX.value = withTiming(screenWidth, { duration: 5000 });
  }, []);

  ...
  return (
    <>
      <Animated.View
        style={[styles.line, animatedLineStyle]}
        onLayout={({ nativeEvent }) => setLineX(nativeEvent.layout.x)}
      />
      <Animated.View style={[styles.square, animatedSquareStyle]} />
    </>
  );
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot for you example 

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to get current value of `Animated.Value` by adding addListener to it. The way how to achieve it is explained in this [article](https://thewebdev.info/2022/02/18/how-to-get-the-current-value-of-animated-value-with-react-native/)

Then you can compare it with position of line and trigger action.